# Communicating with a TCP server via PuTTY

Tags: go, server, tcp, client, putty

How do I close the connection by typing the word "exit" from the PuTTY client? This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    //Ascolta richiesta
    datastream, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer datastream.Close()

    //Accetta richiesta
    for {
        connessione, err := datastream.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        go handle(connessione)
    }
}

//Connessione Handle > Thread
func handle(connessione net.Conn) {

    fmt.Println("Scrivere exit per uscire")

    for {
        data, err := bufio.NewReader(connessione).ReadString('\n')

        

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(data)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves me right, PuTTY is able to use several protocols to access servers, with [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) being used the most.

Most of the time people use PuTTY to access SSH servers, and typing "exit" in an SSH session to terminate it has relatively complex semantics: most of the time, the server runs a [command-line shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Command-line_shells), the SSH protocol is carrying data between that shell and the SSH client, so when the user types "exit" in the client (PuTTY, for instance), the client sends that to the SSH-server and it sends that to the shell; the shell interprets that command, terminates itsef, the SSH server detects that and shuts down its session.
To recap, PuTTY does not in any way handles typing "exit" into it by itself; it merely sends that string to the remote side.

You did not tell us, but form your code, it looks like you have written a plain TCP server (I mean, not an SSH server) and hence looks like PuTTY uses Telnet to access your server.
In this case, typing "exit" into the PuTTY will make it send that line to your Go server, directly, so to terminate your server you have to interpret what is being sent to it, and once it receives a line "exit", it has to terminate the processing loop and close the connection.

Judging from your code, it should be something like

```golang
func handle(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Println("Scrivere exit per uscire")

    for {
        data, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n') 

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println(data)
        if data == "exit" {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we

1. Added a `defer`red statement which closes the connection — so that this happens each time we exit from the connection "handler".
   Not including that was a bug in your original code which would lead to eventual recource exhaustion on the server.
2. Added an `if` statement which analyzes the line of text sent from the client and terminates the handler once that line is "exit".

---

*Update* after the comment thread.

#### The problem

There is a twist which renders the fix I have initially offerred unusable:

- `bufio.Reader.ReadString(delim byte)` is documented as follows

  > `ReadString` reads until the first occurrence of `delim` in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.

  Since the code asked `ReadString` to read until `\n`, when the client sends "exit" followed by a newline character (ASCII LF, 0x0a), `ReadString` returns precisely "exit" plus that LF character in a single piece.
- The Telnet protocol which PuTTY is apparently using, terminates each line the client sends with a [CRLF sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), 0x0b, 0x0a, and that's what gets sent to the server, so the `if` statement in my example is receiving "exit\r\n".

Actually, both facts could have been easily seen if the OP were using something like `fmt.Printf("%q\n", data)` in their debug output statement — as the `%q` formatting verb makes any non-printable character "visible" in the output.

#### The solutions

First, the original code has a bug I haven't spotted on the first read: a new instance of a `bufio.Reader` is created on each loop iteration—throwing away the previous one, if any. But this type is explicitly documented as having permission to buffer any amount of data from the source reader—that is, it's able to consume from the reader more data than it is going to return to the client which made a call to any of the type's reading methods.
This means when a `bufio.Reader` is discarded, the data it has buffered since the last reading call is thrown away, too.
This bug is grave, and is needed to be fixed.

Second, we need to decide what to do with the newline termination character(s).
There are multiple choices:

- Specify precisely which newline format the server supports in its protocol and then implement support for exactly that specification.

  For instance, we can postulate each line in our wire protocol must be terminated by exactly a single LF.
  In this case we might leave the code (almost) as is, but compare the string submitted by the client with "exit\n".

  In this case, talking to the server via the Telnet protocol will *not* work as a Telnet client terminates the lines submitted by the user with CRLF sequences.
- Be lax about the protocol and allow both LFs and CRLFs.

  To support this, the code should somehow deal with the possibility for the client's lines to be terminated either way.
  This could be done, for instance, by trimming the input line before using it in the comparison statement.

I would say the simplest approach is to go with the second option and also use the `bufio.Scanner` type:

```golang
func handle(conn net.Conn) {
  defer conn.Close()

  scanner = bufio.NewScanner(conn)
  for scanner.Scan() {
    data := scanner.Text()

    fmt.Printf("%q\n", data)

    if data == "exit" {
      return
    }
  }

  if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's as you say, but the problem is that I tried this code but it doesn't work, I tried in a thousand ways, but the exit command does not read me, the server continues to go ...

Comment: You fully understand what I need, but trying the code, with the command "exit" it does not come out.

Comment: @FratmCarnal, works for me with your unmodified code (Linux, plain `telnet`): <https://pastebin.com/zQEhtavU> As you can see, I've typed "exit" to the telnet, hit Enter, and it was successfully transferred and handled by your server. May be you're experiencing some weird networking issues (like Windows firewall intervening or whatnot) or PuTTY setup. (The latter can be bypassed by installing `telnet` on Windows — you can google for how to do that.)

Comment: It doesn't work for me if I use Visual Studio Code with the Go language

Comment: I from the PuTTY shell send data that arrives at the visual studio code terminal and after writing "exit" the connection does not close.

Comment: @FratmCarnal, sorry for derailing the exchange but why on Earth have you not stated all those _crucial_ pieces of information in your question? I'm not bitching, but your question is not «how to make my server exit on receiving "exit" from a client?», it's «my server works in a reglar environment but does not work when run under VSCode; what are my options?». These two questions are completely different! Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @FratmCarnal, all-in-all, I suggest you to post another question, detailing _exactly_ what problem you're having. Tag it with `vscode`, too. And first recheck that it works when being run outside VSCode—just like I did to create my paste.

Comment: We are not understanding each other, to me on VSCode everything works, only when I send the "exit" command it does not close the connection, but in the end that's the point it is useless that I ask another question.

Comment: @FratmCarnal, but *your* code does not close the connection because it does not implement this logic. How could it close the connection if there is no code for that? I have demonstrated what code to add, so we're sort of back to square one. I feel like I'm lost in this case.

Comment: @FratmCarnal, basically your "connection handler" code has a loop in which the only exit condition is the code reading from the TCP stream returning an error, so the only way for your code as presented to terminate the connection is to wait until _the client_ closes its side of the TCP connection (and your code does not even close its side of the connection in that case).

Comment: Yes, but in fact I corrected my code with yours but it doesn't work anyway, I said it before, your code doesn't work.

Comment: @FratmCarnal, OK, I see now. The issue is more interesting; I'll post an update to my answer in a short while.